# How to check for mouse click on Area2D in Godot 4?

Tags: mouse, godot4

How do I detect mouse clicks/mouse events in an Area2D's script? Do I use the func _process(delta) function? Let's say I have an area 2D called area. So what should the script be like? I want something like this:

```
extends Area2D


func _process(delta):
    if mouse_touching && mouse_left_down:
        print("clicked on object")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Area2D` has `input_pickable` then it will get a call to `_input_event` when the user clicks it.